# X2go session unresponsive after brief period

Tags: x2go, x2goclient

When I connect with ubuntu gnome x2goclient to a x2goserver running ubuntu xfce, I am unable to resume a suspended session after a short time (+-5 minutes). I've run debug both on client and server to try and look for anything, but no error messages. The display on the client just freezes; the server seems to say it has been succesfully resumed. But the screen is unresponsive. If I terminate, and start a new session, everything works. But then 5 minutes later (after inactivity) the same problem occurs.

After a short period the client then says "no response received from remote server".

The issue does not occur on x2goclient running windows, there the session can be continued later.

Client debug (only relevant parts, cannot post everything here)

```
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:356> Creating new channel for reverse tunnel 57307
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:368> Connecting to "127.0.0.1":4713

x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:392> New channel created
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:6618> Proxy wrote on stderr: "Warning: No data received from remote proxy within 30 seconds.\n"
```

Server info

```
Sep  3 06:59:38 lnz1-inno /usr/bin/x2goumount-session[1567193]: x2goumount-session has been called with options: j.oosterhuis-50-1599113954_stDXFCE_dp24
Sep  3 06:59:38 lnz1-inno /usr/bin/x2goumount-session[1567193]: SSHFS share already unmounted, taking care of further clean-up (C-j.oosterhuis-50-1599113954_stDXFCE_dp24)
Sep  3 06:59:38 lnz1-inno /usr/bin/x2gofeature: x2gofeature called with options: X2GO_FMBINDINGS
Sep  3 06:59:38 lnz1-inno /usr/share/x2go/x2gofeature.d/x2goserver-extensions.features: x2goserver-extensions.features called with options: X2GO_FMBINDINGS
Sep  3 06:59:38 lnz1-inno /usr/share/x2go/x2gofeature.d/x2goserver.features: x2goserver.features called with options: X2GO_FMBINDINGS
Sep  3 06:59:38 lnz1-inno /usr/share/x2go/x2gofeature.d/x2goserver-fmbindings.features: x2goserver-fmbindings.features called with options: X2GO_FMBINDINGS
Sep  3 07:00:12 lnz1-inno /usr/bin/x2goresume-session: x2goresume-session called with options: j.oosterhuis-50-1599113954_stDXFCE_dp24 800x600 adsl 16m-jpeg-9 us pc105/us 0 both no
Sep  3 07:00:12 lnz1-inno /usr/bin/x2gofeature: x2gofeature called with options: X2GO_RUN_EXTENSIONS
Sep  3 07:00:12 lnz1-inno /usr/share/x2go/x2gofeature.d/x2goserver-extensions.features: x2goserver-extensions.features called with options: X2GO_RUN_EXTENSIONS
Sep  3 07:00:12 lnz1-inno /usr/bin/x2goserver-run-extensions: x2goserver-run-extensions called with options: j.oosterhuis-50-1599113954_stDXFCE_dp24 pre-resume
Sep  3 07:00:13 lnz1-inno /usr/bin/x2goresume-session: client 192.168.23.106 has successfully resumed session with ID j.oosterhuis-50-1599113954_stDXFCE_dp24
Sep  3 07:00:13 lnz1-inno /usr/bin/x2gofeature: x2gofeature called with options: X2GO_DESKTOPSHARING
Sep  3 07:00:13 lnz1-inno /usr/share/x2go/x2gofeature.d/x2goserver-extensions.features: x2goserver-extensions.features called with options: X2GO_DESKTOPSHARING
Sep  3 07:00:13 lnz1-inno /usr/share/x2go/x2gofeature.d/x2goserver.features: x2goserver.features called with options: X2GO_DESKTOPSHARING
Sep  3 07:00:13 lnz1-inno /usr/share/x2go/x2gofeature.d/x2goserver-fmbindings.features: x2goserver-fmbindings.features called with options: X2GO_DESKTOPSHARING
Sep  3 07:00:13 lnz1-inno /usr/share/x2go/x2gofeature.d/x2goserver-printing.features: x2goserver-printing.features called with options: X2GO_DESKTOPSHARING
Sep  3 07:00:13 lnz1-inno /usr/share/x2go/x2gofeature.d/x2goserver-x2goagent.features: x2goserver-x2goagent.features called with options: X2GO_DESKTOPSHARING
Sep  3 07:00:13 lnz1-inno /usr/share/x2go/x2gofeature.d/x2goserver-xsession.features: x2goserver-xsession.features called with options: X2GO_DESKTOPSHARING
Sep  3 07:00:13 lnz1-inno /usr/bin/x2gofeature: x2gofeature called with options: X2GO_RUN_EXTENSIONS
Sep  3 07:00:13 lnz1-inno /usr/share/x2go/x2gofeature.d/x2goserver-extensions.features: x2goserver-extensions.features called with options: X2GO_RUN_EXTENSIONS
Sep  3 07:00:13 lnz1-inno /usr/bin/x2goserver-run-extensions: x2goserver-run-extensions called with options: j.oosterhuis-50-1599113954_stDXFCE_dp24 post-resume
Sep  3 07:00:15 lnz1-inno /usr/bin/x2gomountdirs[1568154]: x2gomountdirs has been called with options: dir j.oosterhuis-50-1599113954_stDXFCE_dp24 jacco /home/j.oosterhuis/.x2go/ssh/key.KozDcL /home/jacco/.x2go/S-j.oosterhuis-50-1599113954_stDXFCE_dp24/spool__PRINT_SPOOL___REVERSESSH_PORT__57308
Sep  3 07:00:16 lnz1-inno /usr/bin/x2gomountdirs[1568154]: successfully mounted jacco@127.0.0.1:57308/home/jacco/.x2go/S-j.oosterhuis-50-1599113954_stDXFCE_dp24/spool to /tmp/.x2go-j.oosterhuis/spool/C-j.oosterhuis-50-1599113954_stDXFCE_dp24
```

Which seems to say "succesfully mounted".

Comment: Ubuntu client with gnome, ubuntu server with xfce. I've tested it on windows client, and the issue does not arise.

Comment: Right sorry. Both my laptop and the server run 20.04. A colleague has tested it on his laptop running ubuntu 18.04, same result.

Comment: Have you find a solution to this? It is happening to me in Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Turn off screen saver and you'll be fine.

This inflicted me too when I migrated to the Ubuntu 20.04 LTS server.  I was previously running Debian Jessie on my media server which died recently so switched to Ubuntu.  Turning off screensaver resolved the issue for me.

Comment: Doesn't solve the issue for me. I turned off all screen-saver settings, auto lock, sleep, everything that can be turned off, and the screen still freezes after a period of inactivity.

Comment: Actually seems to have solved it after restarting the server. I'll check a bit more before accepting

Comment: you may also consider to uninstall xfce4-screensaver

Comment: I also needed to disable display power options.

Comment: Specifically, this worked for me: `xset -dpms; xset s off`